# Visual C# 2010: Unable to connect to XAMPP localhost

Tags: c#, mysql, xampp

I am unable to connect to XAMPP localhost in my C# Windows form application.

My code is:

```
SqlConnection connection = null;

        try
        {
            connection = new SqlConnection("user id=root;" + 
            "password=12345678;" + "server=localhost");
            connection.Open();
        }
        catch (Exception exptn)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(exptn.ToString());
        }
```

I made sure to include "using System.Data.SqlClient;" so that my code runs. The timeout error I get at runtime is:

> "System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): A network-related or
>   instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to
>   SQL server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify
>   that the instance name is correct and that SQL server is configured to
>   allow remote connections."

There was more to the error message, but it was uncopyable and too long to post here.  I have tried to install MySql and the .NET MySql connector separately from XAMPP.  I added MySql.Data as a reference in Solution Explorer (My research told me to add MySql.Data and MySql.Web, and MySql.Data was the only one listed in the options.).  Another source told me to add a Microsoft ODBC Data Source in Server/Database explorer, but the option was not available in Database Explorer. I have made sure XAMPP is running and working properly in phpMyAdmin, and I am able to create tables and run queries there. Many sources also seem to have different opinions as to what is needed in the connection string.

I am completely at a loss as to how I am supposed to connect to localhost databases from another application on the same computer. Forgive me if I am overlooking something basic or if this is a noob question, but I know little about connecting to databases (this type of thing is precisely the reason why). Can anyone help me connect to XAMPP localhost from C#?

Comment: `SqlConnection` is for SQL Server, not MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

Install `MySQL Connector` from Oracle and then use class `MySqlConnection`.

Here is the download link -

http://www.mysql.com/products/connector/

Download the driver for ADO.Net and the documentation to use it is here -

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-introduction.html

`SqlConnection` is for MQ SQL server only and thus it is looking for a instance of MS SQL Server to connect to and it fails to connect since none exists. This explains the error message.